# Splitting book into two volumes, each volume into parts

Tags: table-of-contents, book-design

I have a book with about 20 chapters which I want to split into two volumes, each of which will be further subdivided into parts. The first volume will have 4 parts and the second volume should have 3 parts. The page numbers in volume two should be a continuation from volume one.  Below would be a structure of the table of contents for Vol. I.

VOL. I - TITLE

CONTENTS

Preface

PART I. TITLE

1. Chapter 1
   ...
2. Chapter 3
   ...
   ...

PART IV. TITLE

9. Chapter 9
   ...
10. Chapter 11

APPENDIX.

INDEX.

The appendix, index would be shared by both volumes. Also the table of contents in Vol II should have the contents of Vol I following the contents of Vol II. If there is a 'part' environment to create parts, I imagine it to create a coverpage before the part starts identifying the beginning of that part with title text centered in the page.

I am using the svsing6.cls document class http://tug.ctan.org/info/examples/mil3/svsing6.cls

I have looked at [Split a book into multiple volumes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111951/split-a-book-into-multiple-volumes) and [Splitting one volume into two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166753/splitting-one-volume-into-two) But I am not using the book or memoir document class.

Thank you for your time.

Edit: This is how the basic structure looks like.

```
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\include{chapters/preface}

\mainmatter


\part{Part I}
\include{chapters/chap_1}
\include{chapters/chap_2}


\part{Part II}
\include{chapters/chap_3}
\include{chapters/chap_4}
\include{chapters/chap_5}

%\include{chapters/appendix}

% Start of Volume II

\part{Part III}
\include{chapters/chap_6}
\include{chapters/chap_7}

\part{Part IV}
\include{chapters/chap_8}

%\include{chapters/appendix}
```

But I am unable to figure out how to have the exact same appendix after Volume I is done as the one after full document.  Any pointers in that direction are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! So what exactly is the question/the problem? Please post the code that you have so far and specify the problem that you are having with it.

Comment: Basically you need to copy all the code for part, changing the name to volume, using a lower toc counter (-2) and whatever format changes you want.

Comment: On further reflection, you don't want Volume to be like Part, all you want is for it to show up in the table of contents and the title page.  Will each volume have a title as well as a number?  See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344223/continuous-page-numbering-across-separate-tex-pdf-files/344297?s=3|0.0796#344297

Answer (score 1):

If you want the parts in Volume II to restart at 1 automatically, you can use the following.

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{volume}
\renewcommand\thevolume{\@Roman\c@volume}
\@addtoreset{part}{volume}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{volume}vol \thevolume\par
\stepcounter{part}part \thepart\par
\stepcounter{part}part \thepart\par
\stepcounter{volume}vol \thevolume\par
\stepcounter{part}part \thepart\par
\stepcounter{volume}vol \thevolume\par
\stepcounter{part}part \thepart\par
\end{document}
```

---

This is what you get treating volume like part, which is obviously NOT what you want, but does give a starting point for formatting.

```
\documentclass{sving6}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\l@volume[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-3\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       \large \bfseries #1\hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
       \nobreak
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\newcommand\volumename{Volume}

\newcounter{volume}
\renewcommand\thevolume{\@Roman\c@volume}
\@addtoreset{part}{volume}% resets part counter for each volume

\newcommand\volume{\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\vfil\secdef\@volume
  \@svolume}
\def\@volume[#1]#2{\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>-3\refstepcounter{volume}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{volume}{\thevolume\hspace{1em}#1}\else\addcontentsline
  {toc}{volume}{#1}\fi\markboth{}{}{\centering\interlinepenalty\@M\normalfont
  \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>-3\relax\huge\bfseries\volumename~\thevolume\par\vskip20\p@
  \fi\Huge\bfseries#2\par}\@endvolume}
\def\@svolume#1{{\centering\interlinepenalty\@M\normalfont\Huge\bfseries#1\par}%
  \@endvolume}
\def\@endvolume{\vfil\newpage
  \null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}
\makeatletter

\title{My Book}
\author{My Self}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\volume{Vol I}

\part{Part I}
\chapter{chap 1}
\chapter{chap 2}

\part{Part II}
\chapter{chap 3}
\chapter{chap 4}
\chapter{chap 5}

\volume{Vol 2}

\part{Part III}
\chapter{chap 6}
\chapter{chap 7}

\part{Part IV}
\chapter{chap 8}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want the volume name to come before the contents. Each volume is like its own book (with own copy of preface, appendix although identical ) but with page continuation. Also I am looking to have the contents of each volume separately. Is there a way to save table of contents in different files and invoke them at the appropriate point ?

Comment: The table of contents is saved both in aux and toc files.  If you want to get fancy, use the tocloft package.  You still need to copy and rename all the part code from sving6.cls.