# Splitting my document into two volumes does not work

Tags: book-design

I have a document, which I want to put in the following fomrat:

```
Preface
Introduction

Volume One: Dynamic Meteorology
Table of Contents
Chapters

Volume Two: Dynamic Oceanography
Table of Contents
Chapters
```

With apge numbering in volume two continued from volume one.

Using suggestions from various posts on the subject, and particularly this [Splitting one volume into two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166753/splitting-one-volume-into-two?rq=1)

my document loses the Preface, Introduction and table of contents. Instead I have:

```
Volume One
Title

volume one
volume two

blank page
Chapters

Volume Two
Title

volume one
volume two
blank page
Chapters
```

Switching to memoir class as suggested on the above posts, gives errors which are difficult to understand.

Help will be appreciated.

Following comment from @Carlisle I think I can go with \part{partname}, it is better in that it has no volume one, volume two repeated on the same page.
However I still get blank table of contents and blank pages after table of contents (title only), after preface,after introduction and after each page of part1 and part 2. Here is the structure after \begin{document}:

```
\begin{document}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
```

{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{blue}}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}
    {1em}{} 
    \input{Chapters/TitlePage}
    \pagenumbering{roman}

```
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter*{Preface}
\input{Chapters/Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\input{Chapters/Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\part{Dynamic Meteorology}
\chapter{Introduction}\label{ch1}
...

\part{Dynamic Oceanography}
\chapter{chapter1}
...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why did you set the `biblatex` tag?

Comment: I was looking for simply "latex tag" but the suggested tags were coming in combinations: lualatex, xetex, ...

Comment: Thanks. I changed the posting's tag to "book-design".

Comment: use the command `\part` to separate your volumes (you can redefine `\partname` to `Volume`

Comment: Thanks @Carlisle I will try that

Comment: Are you creating one document or two?  One document with two parts is easy.  Two documents with shared TOCs is a bit trickier.

Comment: One document with two parts is ok for me